# How to detect pagebreak in Prince PDF?

Tags: css, pdf, detection, page-break, princexml

I have a generated 100 pages long document with dozens of sections, headers and varying text + image content. There are user inserted pagebreaks as well as injected pagebreaks, but most of the text runs from page to page.

Something that is driving me crazy is that I cannot **detect if an element is the first or the last on the page**.

For example my text-container div has bottom and top margin of 10 mm. If pagebreak happens just before it, it should have 0 top margin. But since I have no way of detecting Prince automated pagebreaks, text-containers have 10mm extra top margin on some pages.

*(this is an example only, the real situation is a little more complex)*

**Is there ANY way to detect what Prince is doing to flowing content?**

Comment: After further investigation I found this thread about margin collapsing at top of the page http://www.princexml.com/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2438. It didn't help much since in my case top margin should be 0 after user defined pagebreaks as well.

Comment: How are you defining your page breaks? `page-break-before: always`? If so couldn't you add `margin-top: 0 !important` to those same elements?

Comment: Sorry, just saw how old this is...

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set the Page height, unless your text will go out from the page. and after set **page-break-after: always** in page container class. then it will works.